# Devise omniauth failure to custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have a custom controller for omniauth_callbacks

```
class People::OmniauthCallbacksController < 
    Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def setup
   ...
 end

 def facebook
   ...
 end

 def google-oauth2
   ...
 end

 def failure
  ...
 end
end
```

And in routes:

```
...
devise_for :people, only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'people/omniauth_callbacks' }
devise_scope :person do
  get '/people/auth/:provider/setup' => 'people/omniauth_callbacks#setup' #needed for devise setup phase hook to work
end
...
```

And when I have fail auth through omniauth I have:

  `Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure`

But I want processing of `People::OmniauthCallbacksController`. How can I setup this?

devise (4.5.0)
omniauth (1.8.1)
rails (4.2.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your devise_scope, you should use:

```
devise_scope :people do
  get '/people/auth/:provider/setup' => 'people/omniauth_callbacks#setup' #needed for devise setup phase hook to work
end
```